# Activity re-creation intent extras are null

Tags: android, android-intent, android-fragments, notifications, activity-lifecycle

My app contains a MainActivity and uses full screen fragments to display content.
I'm trying to achieve the following during app re-creation (When the app has been in background for a long time, gets killed by the system and then it's brought to the foreground)

1. If the user is manually re-creating the app (by selecting the app from the recent's apps list), the Main Activity should re-create and then the last fragment that was fullscreen should recreate. No problem here, this is the standard behaviour.
2. If the app is being re-created because the user touched a push notification, The Main Activity should re-create but the last fragment that was in fullscreen should not re-create. **Instead a new Fragment should be created and displayed**. Why? The push notification contains the info as to what kind of Fragment should be displayed

My approach relies on checking the intent extras that I put when building the notification that starts the Main Activity, That part of the code is not shown for brevity's sake but **I always put some extras in the intent, always**

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //debug
    System.out.println("MainActivity.onCreate() extras:"+getIntent().getExtras());
    if (savedInstanceState!=null && getIntent().getExtras()!=null){
        //case 2. passing null will prevent Fragment recreation
        super.onCreate(null)
    }
    else{
        //case 1.
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
    ...
}

@Override
public void onResume(){
    //debug
    System.out.println("MainActivity.onResume() extras:"+getIntent().getExtras());
    ...
}
```

Now, if the app is not running at all and a notification arrives, I get the following output:

```
MainActivity.onCreate() extras: Bundle[{android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[mParcelledData....
MainActivity.onResume() extras: Bundle[{android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[mParcelledData....
```

When the app is re-created manually by the user I get The following output:

```
MainActivity.onCreate() extras: null
MainActivity.onResume() extras: null
```

When the app is re-created by a notification

```
MainActivity.onCreate() extras: null
MainActivity.onResume() extras: Bundle[{android:viewHierarchyState=Bundle[mParcelledData....
```

This last case is not what I expected, somehow the notification intent extras are only available after calling super.onCreate()

Any ideas on how to achieve 1. and 2.?

**Giant Edit:**
This is the notification code, as you can see, there is a splash screen activity that relays the intent to the Main Activity

GcmIntentService.java

```
@Override protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(extras.getString(KEY_CATEGORY), extras.getString(KEY_CONTENT));
        }
    }
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String category, String content) {
    category = evaluateCategory(category);
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
    mIntent.putExtra(KEY_CATEGORY, Integer.valueOf(category));
    mIntent.putExtra(KEY_NEW, true);
    mIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Integer.valueOf(category), mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                                                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo_actionbar)
                                                //customize notification

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(Integer.valueOf(category), mBuilder.build());
```

SplashActivity.java

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent mIntent = getIntent();
    if (mIntent.getExtras()!=null){
        category = mIntent.getExtras().getInt(GcmIntentService.KEY_CATEGORY);
        isNew = mIntent.getExtras().getBoolean(GcmIntentService.KEY_NEW);
    }
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            if (category!=null ){
                mainIntent.putExtra(GcmIntentService.KEY_CATEGORY, category);
                mainIntent.putExtra(GcmIntentService.KEY_NEW, isNew);
            }
            startActivity(mainIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DELAY);
}
```

Comment: What version of Android? If your testing this on KitKat notifications are different on there. Can you post your notification building code?

Comment: Version is 4.4.2. I've added de notification code, It goes like this GcmIntentService > SplashActivity > MainActivity

Comment: did you solve your problem ?

Answer (score 3):

What about overriding onNewIntent(Intent intent) method provided by Activity ?

1. Read savedInstanceState can be null and getIntent() can contain extra with your GCM.
2. [According to Android Developers:](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onNewIntent(android.content.Intent))

> **protected void onNewIntent (Intent intent)**
>
> This is called for activities that set launchMode to "singleTop" in
> their package, or if a client used the FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP flag
> when calling startActivity(Intent). In either case, when the activity
> is re-launched while at the top of the activity stack instead of a new
> instance of the activity being started, onNewIntent() will be called
> on the existing instance with the Intent that was used to re-launch
> it.
>
> An activity will always be paused before receiving a new intent, so
> you can count on onResume() being called after this method.
>
> Note that getIntent() still returns the original Intent. You can use
> setIntent(Intent) to update it to this new Intent.